# AngularJS unexpected routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have .NET Core Single Page application with AngularJS routing and this app have some links (*"Main page"*, *"Additional info"*, *"Contacts"*, etc) at the layout. When user click to *"Additional info"* by link, it's displayed **"/app/additionalInfo"** page, but when user copy-paste this url to address field, my application opens **"/app/additionalInfo"** firstly, but then browser make redirect to *"Main page"*.

Can anybody explain me, how to find reason of this strange behaviour and how to fix it?

Comment: Please could you share the code in plunker !

Comment: it is getting redirected to `.otherwise()` part. Share your code. I think the url might be looking for some param and u are not passing it. or worst, you are putting wrong route